# Find sum of longest run in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code, this should return 45 as answer instead I'm getting 8.
This code works fine for smaller lists.

I get proper answer for this list [1, 2, 3, 2, 1] as 6.

```
def longest_run(L):

    bestDec = 0
    bestInc = 0

    currentSum = 0
    lastNum = 0
    for i in L:
        if i <= lastNum:
            currentSum += i
        else:
            if currentSum > bestDec:
                bestDec = currentSum  
            currentSum = i
        lastNum = i


    currentSum = 0
    lastNum = 0
    for i in L:
        if i >= lastNum:
            currentSum += i            
        else:
            if currentSum > bestInc:
                bestInc = currentSum

            currentSum = i
        lastNum = i

    if bestDec >= bestInc:  
        return bestDec
    else:
        return bestInc
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]        
print(longest_run(L))
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by a "run"? (We should not have to examine your code to figure that out.) What should be returned if there is more than one run of the same maximum length?

Comment: I used classes to solve this final exam problem, breaking it down into subproblems. The question asks you to find the longest run (consecutive sequence) of ascending or descending values, assuming L is a list of integers. I had two classes with similar behavior except one had reversed comparison logic. The superclass took care of everything else. I'd share the solution, except I'm not supposed to do that until the exam deadline passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the cumulative sum of a list of integers till they are increasing, what about:

```
def longest_run(L):
    if len(L)==0: return 0
    cs = L[0]
    for i in range(1,len(L)):
        if L[i]>L[i-1]:
            cs+=L[i]
        else:
            break
    return cs
```

Answer (score 0):

not working as well
for list [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, -10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
answer should be 11 but this code gives 3